# Getting error "Failed to invoke createSingle" while using salesforce connector in mule

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-component, connector, anypoint-studio

I am using Salesforce connector to insert the customer details in the salesforce. I have used salesforce basic authentication configuration and operation used is "Create Single"  and object type is  "Account", and I am passing the whole payload to the salesforce connector. But when it hits the salesforce connector it throws error saying "Failed to invoke createSingle".

Can someone explain me why I am getting this error? Is there something that I am missing? I am unable to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It was a miss from my side. The payload which I was sending to the connector had one extra field mapping and that is why it was throwing the error as the fields were not matching with the connector fields.